# how to reach from terminal 2 to terminal 1 in Mumbai airport

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-transfer, mumbai, airport-terminals

1. Are Santa cruz domestic airport T1 and Sahar T1 airport same ?
2. I am travelling from Goa to Mumbai with Jet Airways, it will be arrived on 5:40 am at Mumbai Airport Terminal 2 and then from Mumbai Airport Terminal 1 I have to take another flight (Indigo) to Nagpur on 8:20 am (departure time). Could anyone let me know it is enough time to reach from terminal 2 to terminal 1 with all baggage.
3. What is best way to reach from terminal 2 to terminal 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer in 2 ways:

1. Look for transfer to T1 (bus) after you clear the customs, takes atleast 1h
2. Exit T2 and take a taxi to T1 (indigo serves in T1), bit faster.

http://www.csia.in/tofrom/In-terminal-transfer.aspx
http://www.mumbaiairport.com/terminals.php